# Is it possible to obtain touch co-ordinates on homescreen or any other activity outside our application in Android?

Tags: android

So this what I want to achieve:

1. There is a overlay icon on my homescreen. On clicking this overlay
   icon the user must select the area on screen (homescreen in this
   case) by dragging his finger.
2. To do this I want the touch co ordinates of the user i.e
   co-ordinates at which the user touches the screen and the
   co-ordinates at which user release the screen.
3. This co-ordinates are then received by a service/activity.

I know that this is possible to do using onTouchListener within our own activity .But is it possible to do it outside our application as shown in above example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would be a major security issue. Imagine creating a app that registers all your inputs... Aka keylogger.

Comment: You could create an activity with transparent view. This way you'd have your  own activity, on which you can intercept touch events, but the user sees homescreen.

Comment: Transparent activity does the job.Thanks